# Constant vector fields on $T^{2n}=\mathbb{R}^{2n}/\mathbb{Z}^{2n}$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

I want to know what constant vector fields on $T^{2n}$ look like.

We have obvious coordinates $(\theta_1,\phi_1,....,\theta_n,\phi_n)$ on $T^{2n}$. Let $X$ be a constant vector field on $T^{2n}$, i.e. $X(\theta_1,\phi_1,....,\theta_n,\phi_n)=v$ for some $v\in \mathbb R^{2n}$. It seems that we must have $X$ as some linear combination of $\partial/\partial \theta_i$'s and $\partial/\partial \phi_j$'s.

But It also feels that this not need be the cause because we could have chosendi some different coordinate system.

Comment: Choosing another coordinate system (defined on all of $\mathbb{T}^n$) generates a change of basis in the tangent space. Thus every "constant" vector field written as a linear combination of $\partial_{\theta},\partial_{\phi}$ can be written as a linear combination of the new basis of the tangent space. The change of basis matrix is the Jacobian of the change of coordinates